# JPQL: convert varchar to number

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpql

How can i convert varchar to number in JPQL ???

I managed to do that in sql (Oracle) with this query:

```
SELECT Decode(Upper(column_name), Lower(column_name), To_Number(column_name), -1)
FROM table
```

I want to do this conversion with JPQL.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do the next:

```
CAST(e.salary AS NUMERIC(10,2))
```

Additionally, you can try:

- `FUNC('TO_NUMBER', e.areaCode)`, `FUNC` allows for a database function to be call from JPQL.
- `SQL('CAST(? AS CHAR(3))', e.areaCode)`, `SQL` allows for the usage and integration of SQL within JPQL.

Comment: thanks for your help

FUNC('TO_NUMBER', e.areaCode) works very well but there is an exception: I have java.sql.SQLException when i have for exemple '123TA' as value for e.areaCode in the database.

I explain my objective:
Data of my table in the database are:

Column
   2
   5
   AA
   8
   TT

In JPQL i want to select the max of 'column'

 the result is 8

Comment: Note that unless I'm wrong, `FUNC()` and `SQL()` are eclipselink specific. However `FUNCTION()` was introduced in JPA 2.1 (JEE7) which replaces `FUNC()` while being portable. Also see http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2012/05/jpql-vs-sql-have-both-with-eclipselink.html